# nano: Move forwards/backwards one word with META+Left / META+Right

Tags: unix, terminal, nano

One can move forwards / backwards one word using Ctrl+Space and Meta+Space respectively.
How can I bind META+Left arrow to move backwards one word / META+Right to move forwards one word?

Thx for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual page for [nanorc](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/nanorc.5.html#KEY%20BINDINGS), you cannot do this.  It does not accept bindings for special keys modified by meta. This is what it says regarding **`M-`** (the meta-modifier):

> **`M-`**
>   followed by a printable character or the word "Space". Example: M-C

A similar question was asked in *[Bind Ctrl+Right to nextword in nano (as it is in all other apps)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49530/bind-ctrlright-to-nextword-in-nano-as-it-is-in-all-other-apps)*